# Is it allowed to work part time in Schengen countries while having a work permit from an Employer?

Tags: working-visas

If am holding a Schengen  work permit am I allowed to do part time Jobs?

Comment: There is no such thing as a Schengen work permit, so you need to clarify exactly what kind of work permit you have, for a specific country.

Comment: Lets say I Have Hungary work permit  will I be allowed to work Part time Jobs?

Comment: Hi Dr.Snoopy Lets say I have Hungary workpermit which is valid for one year will I  be allowed to do part time jobs ?

Comment: Are you asking if one work permit allows you to have more than one job? Or whether the employer sponsoring your work visa will allow you to work part-time (for them and/or other employers)? What type of work visa are you applying for?

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that you cannot assume that it is allowed. There is no such thing as a “Schengen work permit”, permission to work is still (largely) regulated by EU member states separately (i.e. without much constraint from EU law). In any given country, you might typically find up to a dozen or so types of work permits designed to cover specific cases. This means that there are hundreds of different work permits in the Schengen area, each with their own set of rules.

To get a definitive answer, you will therefore need to specify what exact type of work permit you hold (or hope to hold in the future). There are certainly work permits tied to a specific employer or position, work permits limited to an industry or compensation level, and work permits with no restrictions so anything is possible.

Furthermore, you main work contract might forbid additional jobs and your employer might even have legal obligations to enforce that (to ensure your overall working time doesn't exceed the maximum) but that's not related to the work permit per se.